# React Redux: Different actions for list items

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

I have a list consisting of React components:

```
        <div className="card-list">
            {cards.map((card, i) => (
                <Card card={card} key={card.cardId} index={i}/>
            ))}
        </div>
```

The problem is that clicking on a card should open a modal window for the card that was clicked. To call the modal window I use the following code inside the Card component:

```
    const Card = ({card, key, index}) => {
        const dispatch = useDispatch();
        const showModal = useSelector(state => state.modal.showContentModal);

        return (
            <div>
                //this is card view
                <div onClick={() => dispatch(showContentModal())}>    
                    <h3>{card.name}</h3>
                </div>

                //this is modal window
                <div id={`modal-overlay-container-${key}`} className={`modal-overlay ${showModal && "active"}`}>
                    <div id={`modal-div-${key}`} className={`modal ${showModal && "active"}`}>
                        <p className="close-modal" onClick={() => dispatch(hideContentModal())}>
                            <svg viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                                <path fill="#8e54e9" d="..."/>
                            </svg>
                        </p>
                        <div className="modal-content">
                        <CardContent card={card} index={index}/>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
  }

  export default Card;
```

The `showСontentModal()` action changes the Boolean flag, which makes the modal window `active`, and `hideModalContent()` does the opposite. But because all the components in the list are linked to a single action, clicking on any card opens a modal window for all of them. Is there any way to trigger an action only for a specific card?

Answer (score 0):

I see two ways you could solve this.

1. Use local state inside card component instead of redux state
2. Use card id instead of boolean in `state.modal.showContentModal`

If you don't need `state.modal.showContentModal` in other components then I would prefer first option.

```
const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false)

const handleOpenModal = () => setShowModal(true)

  <div onClick={handleOpenModal}>    
    <h3>{card.name}</h3>
  </div>
```